# finite dimensional k-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we are given two finite dimensional $k$-algebras $A$ and $B$. Suppose furthermore that we are given an injective map of sets $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $e_i \mapsto f(e_i)$, where $e_i$ is the basis of $A$.

Can one extend that map $f$ to an $k$-algebra homomorphism $h:A\rightarrow B$ such that for example $h(e_i)=f(e_i)$?

Comment: If $f$ is already defined on all of $A$, what do you mean by "extend"?

Comment: $f$ is defined on all of $A$.

Comment: extend in the the sence that one could find an $k$-algebra homomorphism $h:A\rightarrow B$ such that $h(e_i)=f(e_i)$? Or is there a $k$-algebra homomorphism that one can construct of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Consider $A:=B:=k^n$ with $n\ge 3$ and multiplication defined by the linear extension of $e_ie_j:=e_{(i+j)\,\text{mod}\, n}$.

Then $f(e_0):=e_1$ would imply $h(e_0)=e_1$ though
$$e_1=h(e_0)=h(e_0e_0)\ \ne\ h(e_0)h(e_0)=e_1e_1=e_2$$
so $h$ could not be a homomorphism.

Comment: Even better, it is enough to assume that $e_0$ is the identity of the algebra to get this counterexample.